# Difference between PDO::FETCH_* and the casting

Tags: php, casting, pdo, fetch

I want to know the real difference in PHP PDO between the cast variable and the constant PDO::FETCH_* for the return query

Example:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

OR

```
$row = (object) $stmt->fetch();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no significant difference, but obviously the first line does less work: it fetches the data and fills an object, while the second one fetches the data, fills an array and then casts the array to the object.

You could also look at http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php

Comment: The second fetches according to the value of `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` which defaults to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` (an array). You can set the default fetch mode so you don't need to specify it in each call to `PDOStatement::fetch()`

Comment: @Phil: yes, and this is irrelevant to the question I think

Comment: It is relevant to your answer though

Answer (score 0):

[Method](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) `stmt->fetch();` return an indexed array (PDO::FETCH_BOTH) by both column name and zero-indexed array and  `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` method returns anonymous object with property names that correspond to the `column` names returned in your result set.